# Listbox ItemTemplate events not working in WP8 MVVM?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, listbox, command

I have a class named `MizahPanoramaItems`, a List named `PanoramaKarikaturItems` and a ViewModel named `MizahViewModel`.  My problem is my listbox' datatemplate's events not working.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <phone:Panorama SelectionChanged="panaromaMain_SelectionChanged" 
                    x:Name="panaromaMain" Title="mizah" 
                    Style="{StaticResource PanoramaStyle}" 
                    Background="#FFECF0F1" Foreground="#FF040202">
        <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="100" Margin="0,20,0,0"></TextBlock>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="panoramaKarikatur" Header="karikatür" Orientation="Horizontal" Foreground="#A6CC33">
            <ListBox Margin="0,0,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding PanoramaKarikaturItems}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <MetroEventToCommand:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
                                <MetroEventToCommand:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PanoramaTypeSelection}" Event="Tap"/>
                            </MetroEventToCommand:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
                            <c4f:Tile Width="410" Height="200" Margin="0,12,0,0"  Background="{Binding ElementName=panoramaKarikatur,Path=Foreground}" Label="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White">
                                <Grid>
                                    <c4f:TileNotification Background="White" Content="{Binding Count}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=panoramaKarikatur,Path=Foreground}"/>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath,Converter={StaticResource UriToImage}}" Stretch="None" Width="140" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </c4f:Tile>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>.....
```

Here is my list in ViewModel;

```C#
private List<MizahPanoramaItems> panoramaKarikaturItems;
public List<MizahPanoramaItems> PanoramaKarikaturItems
{
    get { return panoramaKarikaturItems; }
    set { SetProperty<List<MizahPanoramaItems>>(ref panoramaKarikaturItems, value, "PanoramaKarikaturItems"); }
}
```

Here is my MizahPanoramaItems Class

```C#
public class MizahPanoramaItems:NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MizahPanoramaItems()
    {
        PanoramaTypeSelection = new DelegateCommand(PanoramatypeSelectionAction);
    }

    public enum Types
    {
        Caps,
        Karikatur,
        DiziFilm
    }

    private int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { SetProperty<int>(ref _count, value, "Count"); }
    }

    private Types _type;
    public Types Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set { SetProperty<Types>(ref _type, value, "Type"); }
    }

    private string _path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _path, value, "Path"); }
    }

    private string _pathName;
    public string PathName
    {
        get { return _pathName; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _pathName, value, "PathName"); }
    }

    private string _imagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _imagePath; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _imagePath, value, "ImagePath"); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _name, value, "Name"); }
    }

    public ICommand PanoramaTypeSelection { get; set; }
    public void PanoramatypeSelectionAction()
    {
    }
}
```

and my command implementation;

```C#
public ICommand PanoramaTypeSelection { get; set; }
public void PanoramatypeSelectionAction()
{
    //it is not working
}

public MizahPanoramaItems()
{
    PanoramaTypeSelection = new DelegateCommand(PanoramatypeSelectionAction);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that  <MetroEventToCommand:EventToCommand  does require some parameterized Command?

Comment: @verdesrobert thanks but it is not require commandparameter.